# Heads and Tails - Trying to get first line and last ten lines of each file

Tags: shell, unix, pipe, tail, unix-head

I've got a directory of output files that I'd like to display the first line of each file and the last ten lines of each file in order.

I've got part of the command down:

```
ls output/*Response | sort -t_ --key=2 -g | xargs tail | less
```

Which give me something like this:

```
==> output/Acdb_18_Response <==
150707,"SOVO","Other","","","","","","160x600",0,0,1432,0,0,1432
167493,"Asper","Other","","","","","","160x600",143200,0,0,1432,0,0
269774,"AIKA","Other","","","","","","160x600",0,1432,0,0,1432,0
342275,"Lorrum","Other","","","","","","160x600",0,0,1432,0,0,1432
347954,"Game","Other","","","","","","160x600",0,1432,0,0,1432,0
418858,"Technologies","Other","","","","","","160x600",0,1432,0,0,1432,0
24576,"Media ","Other","","","","","","300x600",0,0,1432,0,0,1432
23351," Plus","Other","","","","","","425x600",0,4296,0,0,4296,0
#rowcount=79
```

which is nice but I'd like to include the first line to get the header.  I tried tee'ing the output to head but so far I haven't been able to figure out how to arrange the pipes.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ls output/*Response | sort -t_ --key=2 -g \
    | xargs -I {} sh -c 'head -1 {}; tail {}' | less
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try the following:

```
ls output/*Response | sort -t_ --key=2 -g | ((head -n 1) && (tail -n 10)) | less
```